# Insert records into one table using key from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with year, start and end columns like below. It has several years in it. Do not ask me why there is a year called 4 in there because I could not tell you. I just know that it cannot be removed from the table or else the web application will break.

```
year    start       end
2019    2019-01-01  2019-12-31
4       2019-04-01  2020-03-31
```

I use this query to insert records into another table.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, other, medicaid, commercial, year)
SELECT id, other, 
medicaid, commercial, 
4 as year 
FROM crosstab_table
```

As you can see 4 is hardcoded in the query. How do I change this query to insert records for all years that are in table1? For example, how do I convert the two queries below into one query using the table with the years in it.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, other, medicaid, commercial, year)
SELECT id, other, 
medicaid, commercial, 
4 as year 
FROM crosstab_table;

INSERT INTO table2 (id, other, medicaid, commercial, year)
SELECT id, other, 
medicaid, commercial, 
2019 as year 
FROM crosstab_table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b0a50dc02458d2e12a49154ccbef7ffc)

You could use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, other, medicaid, commercial, year)
SELECT 
    ct.id, ct.other, ct.medicaid, ct.commercial, 
    s.year
FROM crosstab_table ct
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT year FROM table1
) s;
```

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for accepting. I'd appreciate if you could UPVOTE as well :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have duplicates in `table1` -- or if you want to insert the duplciates -- then just `CROSS JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, other, medicaid, commercial, year)
    SELECT ct.id, ct.other, ct.medicaid, ct.commercial, t1.year 
    FROM crosstab_table ct CROSS JOIN
         table1 t1;
```

If you have duplicates but want only one value, then use a subquery with `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, other, medicaid, commercial, year)
    SELECT ct.id, ct.other, ct.medicaid, ct.commercial, t1.year 
    FROM crosstab_table ct CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT DISTINCT year FROM table1 t1) t1;
```